# Importing aggregates either through the aggregate name or through part names

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

The following works **perfectly fine**:

```
// libPart1.js
export default 'file part1.js';

// libPart2.js
export default 'file part2.js';

// lib.js
import libPart1 from './libPart1';
import libPart2 from './libPart2';

export default {
    libPart1, libPart2
}

// main1.js
import lib from './lib';

console.dir(lib.libPart1);
console.dir(lib.libPart2);
```

I can also use named imports:

```
// lib.js
export {default as libPart1} from './libPart1';
export {default as libPart2} from './libPart2';

// main2.js
import {libPart1, libPart2} from './lib';

console.dir(libPart1);
console.dir(libPart2);
```

Nevertheless, I would like to write `lib.js` in such a way that both `main1.js` and `main2.js` work fine.

I'm using webpack if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't default-export object literals. Always use named exports. To enable the style with the `lib` object, use a *namespace import*, in the `main1.js` file where you are importing the module. Don't change the export declarations.

```
// lib.js
export {default as libPart1} from './libPart1';
export {default as libPart2} from './libPart2';
```

```
// main1.js
import * as lib from './lib';
//     ^^^^^^^^
console.dir(lib.libPart1);
console.dir(lib.libPart2);
```

```
// main2.js
import {libPart1, libPart2} from './lib';

console.dir(libPart1);
console.dir(libPart2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, there must be a way for that to work because `main1.js` and `main2.js` exist in my code base and they work. The only difference is that `lib.js`, `libPart1.js` and `libPart2.js` all use AMD.

Comment: If `lib.js` uses AMD, then it's probably the leniency of your transpiler that allows both styles.

Comment: Good enough! Thank you. As we speak, I'm rewriting thousands of JS files to use named imports everywhere :-).